# grails 3 webflow not working

Tags: grails, spring-webflow

Long time user of grails but, this is my first grails3 project. The webflow plugin doesn't seem to be working for me.

I get **404 errors** when I go to {proj}/quote/new

**build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.grails.plugins:webflow:2.1.0"
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@Secured('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')
class QuoteController {

    def newFlow = {

        step1{
            on("next").to("step2")
        }
        step2{
            on("next").to("finish")
        }
        finish{
        }
    }
```

**Views:**

```
/views/quote/new/step1.gsp
/views/quote/new/step2.gsp
/views/quote/new/finish.gsp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webflow was never ported to Grails 3. You can't use that version because it is designed for Grails 2.